# Java- For loop with a switch statement containing default case. How can I get the default case to print the output only once?

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, default

The following default statement does exactly what its supposed to: 
            catching all characters not mentioned in the above cases, AND notifying 
            me (after running through the string), that there was an invalid character
            entered somewhere in there. However, if there was two invalid characters:
            the println statement will print twice. If there were three: three times, etc.
            In a string of 100,000 characters, it would be inefficient to print the line so many times.

How would I be able to get it to print only once, no matter how many invalid characters 
            were entered? 
            Please advise and thank you in advance for helping a Java novice!

```
  //for loop to calculate how many A's, G's, T's, and C's in the string
  //default statement at the end of the switch statements to weed out 
  //invalid characters. 
  for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
  {
     ch = dna.charAt(i);
     switch (ch)    
     {
        case 'A':   aCount++;
                    break;
        case 'C':   cCount++;
                    break;
        case 'G':   gCount++;
                    break;
        case 'T':   tCount++;
                    break;
        default: 
           System.out.println("An invalid character was entered.");
     }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to continue counting even after you've encountered an invalid character: introduce a boolean flag the indicates whether you've seen an invalid character already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 //done by Nadim Baraky
 //this program calculates the number of A's, C's, G's & T's;
 //it prints a statement once as you wished in case invalid characters where entered

public class ACGT_DNA {


  public static void main (String[] args) {
     //the counter is set to be 1;
     int length, counter=1; 
     int aCount =0, cCount=0, gCount =0, tCount=0;

     char ch;

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter your string: ");
     String dna = scan.next();
     scan.close();
     length = dna.length();


 for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
    ch = dna.charAt(i);

    switch (ch) {

      case 'A':   aCount++; 
                  break;
      case 'C':   cCount++;
                  break;
      case 'G':   gCount++;
                  break;
      case 'T':   tCount++;
                  break;
      default: 
         if(counter==1) { 
             System.out.println("An invalid character was entered.");
             counter++;
             //after counter is being incremented, the if statement won't be true; so no matter how invalid characters you enter, the statement will be just be printed once.
         }

    }
}

    System.out.println("A's " + aCount);
    System.out.println("C's " + cCount);    
    System.out.println("G's " + gCount);    
    System.out.println("T's " + tCount);

}
```

}